# Creating new localdb database error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, localdb

I'm learning Entity Framework and I'm trying to create a new databse. I go to  `Server Explorer -> Data Connections -> Add Connection` and type in `(localdb)\v11.0` as the server name.

But I keep getting this error...

> An error occured while establishing a connection to server. Server was not found or accessible

I've only recently installed VS Express for Web with Localdb. Do I need to configure this first?

[image]

Comment: Are you using SQL Express 2014 local db? If so try using '(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB' as the connection string

Comment: That worked. Thanks. How could I have found out this name?

Comment: MSDN Docs for SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202%28v=sql.120%29.aspx (Theres also a bug report open on this issue https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/845278/sql-server-2014-express-localdb-does-not-create-automatic-instance-v12-0 where the name was incorrect, but this has been fixed now)

Answer (score 0):

Just posting comment as answer for clarity.

Issue here was that the incremental localdb naming was taken out in SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB and changed to '(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB'

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

(Bug report about incorrect documentation https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/845278/sql-server-2014-express-localdb-does-not-create-automatic-instance-v12-0)